# FadeInImage onFocusChange regenerate

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Im trying to use FadeInImage to show whole screen background images, change them with onFocusChange..

Currently only the initial image uses fade then the image just being replaced.

Looking for some help:

How to use FadeInImage so onFocusChange result nw back images fading in..

Maybe use to another widget.

code:
https://gist.github.com/andraskende/4dac77fed94b9e4f131c9f644e51bc62#file-videos-dart-L80-L88

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
          placeholder: kTransparentImage,
          image: background,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          fadeInDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        ),
```

.....

```
child: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: providerApp.videos.length,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Focus(
      canRequestFocus: false,
      onFocusChange: (bool) {
        if (bool) {
          setState(() {
            background = providerApp.videos[index].image;
            description =
                providerApp.videos[index].description;
          });
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 2):

Try use **UniqueKey** like this:

```
FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          placeholder: kTransparentImage, 
          image: background,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          fadeInDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        ),
```

In this case, the **FadeInImage** will be rebuilt, when call **setState** method, and will not lose animation